# cmake put special target in special dir

Tags: cmake

The `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` in cmake, set this variable to specify a common place where CMake should put all executable files (instead of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR).
Is there method make only special target executable file in my special dir( my working dir ), the other target(like test target don't put there )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the executable target's `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property, e.g.:

```
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "special_dir")
```